# Turning data points of a dataframe into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
   name    sample
 1  a      Category 1: qwe, asd (line break) Category 2: sdf, erg
 2  b      Category 2: sdf, erg(line break) Category 5: zxc, eru
...
30  p      Category 1: asd, Category PE: 2134, EFDgh, Pdr tke, err
```

I need to end up with:

```
   name    qwe   asd   sdf   erg   zxc   eru 2134  EFDgh  Pdr tke  err
 1  a       1     1     1     1    0     0    0     0       0       0
 2  b       0     0     1     1    1     1    0     0       0       0
...
30  p       0     1     0     0    0     0    0     1       1       0
```

I'm honestly not even sure where to begin with this one, my first though is to split it at the line break but I kind of get lost after.

Comment: what is in your `sample` column ? is it a string ? Some object ?

Comment: Because its pandas the column is of dtype object but they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with regex pattern to find all words with 3 characters with [negative lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) for non character symbols. Then you could join obtained lists with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and get your dummies with [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). Then you could drop extra columns:

```
df['new'] = df['sample'].str.findall('(?<!\w)\w{3}(?!\w)')
df_dummies = df['new'].str.join('_').str.get_dummies(sep='_')
df = pd.concat([df, df_dummies], axis=1)

In [215]: df['new']
Out[215]:
1    [qwe, asd, sdf, erg]
2    [sdf, erg, zxc, eru]
Name: new, dtype: object

In [216]: df
Out[216]:
  name                                             sample                    new  asd  erg  eru  qwe  sdf  zxc 
1    a  Category 1: qwe, asd (line break) Category 2: ...   [qwe, asd, sdf, erg]    1    1    0    1    1    0
2    b  Category 2: sdf, erg(line break) Category 5: z...   [sdf, erg, zxc, eru]    0    1    1    0    1    1
```

After dropping extra columns you'll get your result:

```
df = df.drop(['sample', 'new'], axis=1)

In [218]: df
Out[218]:
  name  asd  erg  eru  qwe  sdf  zxc
1    a    1    1    0    1    1    0
2    b    0    1    1    0    1    1
```

Comment: Works perfect, however I found that deep in the data (not very familiar with it) there are entries like "Category 12: werr, nm eetgd" so simpyl matching 3 letter words work for all of it. Any ideas on how to generalize?

Comment: @MArroyo could you add that example for your question and expected output?